# How to get distinct value in the result list of a groupBy

Tags: kotlin

I have a custom view as below, which works fine.

```
val list = listOf(Pair("A", 1), Pair("A", 2), Pair("A", 1), Pair("B", 5))
val map = list.groupBy ({ it.first }, {it.second})
```

The result I get is

```
map = {A = [1, 2, 1], B = [5]}
```

However, I would like to only have distinct value in the list i.e.

```
map = {A = [1, 2], B = [5]}
```

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can do the job:

```
val list = listOf(Pair("A", 1), Pair("A", 2), Pair("A", 1), Pair("B", 5))
val map = list.groupBy ({ it.first }, {it.second}).mapValues { it.value.distinct() }
```

Comment: just as a side-note: on `groupBy` you create a `Map` which you immediately discard on the `mapValues`-call... the same applies to the list  which is discarded on the `distinct()`-call... but that's probably only a detail...

Answer (score 2):

You may call `.distinct()` on the list first. Equality for pairs is defined as equality of both of its components.

So after calling

```
val list = listOf(Pair("A", 1), Pair("A", 2), Pair("A", 1), Pair("B", 5)).distinct()
```

`list` would contain `[(A, 1), (A, 2), (B, 5)]`. Then you can use `.groupBy()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use .single() to validate you aren't getting duplicates

```
val list = listOf(Pair("A", 1), Pair("A", 2), Pair("A", 1), Pair("B", 5))
val map = list.groupBy ({ it.first }, {it.second}).mapValues { it.value.single() }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following interesting sooner or later, using [Grouping / group-and-fold](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-grouping/index.html#grouping):

```
val map = list.groupingBy { it.first }
        .fold(mutableSetOf<Int>()) { acc, e ->
            acc.apply {
                add(e.second)
            }
        }
```

If you don't like that the `MutableSet` is exposed (as the type of `map` now would be `Map<String, MutableSet<Int>>`), you can still set the type of the `map` explicitly, e.g. `val map : Map<String, Set<Int>> = ...`

Or: if you require such functionality more often, you may even want to consider your own extension function similar to `groupBy`:

```
inline fun <T, K, V> Iterable<T>.groupByDistinctValues(keySelector: (T) -> K, valueTransform: (T) -> V): Map<K, Set<V>> = groupByDistinctValuesTo(LinkedHashMap(), keySelector, valueTransform)
inline fun <T, K, V, M : MutableMap<in K, MutableSet<V>>> Iterable<T>.groupByDistinctValuesTo(destination: M, keySelector: (T) -> K, valueTransform: (T) -> V): M {
    for (element in this) {
        val key = keySelector(element)
        val list = destination.getOrPut(key) { mutableSetOf() }
        list.add(valueTransform(element))
    }
    return destination
}
```

which you can then use similar to the following:

```
val map = list.groupByDistinctValues({it.first}) { it.second }
// where map is then of type Map<String, Set<Int>>
```